# Sonar rule: Functions should not be defined inside loops

Tags: javascript, function, loops, sonarqube

Defining a function inside of a loops can yield unexpected results because under the covers, only a single instance of the function is defined. Rather than creating new function instances, the loop iterations simply update the function's variables. Instead, the function should be returned.

Noncompliant Code Example

```
var funs = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 13; i++) {
  funs[i] = function() { // Non-Compliant
    return i;
  };
}
print(funs[0]()); // 13 instead of 0
print(funs[1]()); // 13 instead of 1
print(funs[2]()); // 13 instead of 2
print(funs[3]()); // 13 instead of 3
```

...

I've been thinking but can't figure out the compliant solution. What should it be?

Comment: _"only a single instance of the function is defined"_ - That's not true... The output is wrong/as it is because of the scope of variables defined with `var`

Answer (score 0):

Using a local variable will do the trick.

```
var funs = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 13; i++) {
  let localIndex = i;
  funs[i] = function() { // Non-Compliant
    return localIndex;
  };
}
print(funs[0]()); // 0
print(funs[1]()); // 1
print(funs[2]()); // 2
print(funs[3]()); // 3
```